# Wordpress REST API wp/v2 not found

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I created a rest API key in Woocommerce for my e-commerce site with WordPress infrastructure and entered the screens of Mintsoft company. The products are transferred very correctly, the orders are not reflected and the following error appears in the site health data.

The REST API is one way that WordPress and other applications communicate with the server. For example, the block editor screen relies on the REST API to display and save your posts and pages.

When testing the REST API, an unexpected result was returned:

REST API Endpoint: https://xxxxx.co.uk/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post?context=edit
REST API Response: (404) Not Found

We tried a way to solve the problem but it didn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.